# Cypress not used for tests

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cypress

So, I am trying to create some sort of bot to interact with Twitter. I am familiar with Cypress and wouldn´t be a problem at all learn how to deal with Selenium, but my point is: for what I´ve been reading, they´re both specific for testing, and what I want to do is not exactly testing, but keep an algorithm running for as long as I want.

I can obviously make a loop on the Cypress or the Selenium code, but I don´t see it as the easier way to deal with the problem.
So my question is: is there some ideal framework to keep pressing buttons or typing stuff for a few days on a webpage, not for testing, but to automatically interact with other accounts?

Comment: Selenium is exactly that

Comment: going with Selenium then. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

What you need is what is called an `autoclicker`.

Although this can be done with `Selenium`, there are simpler and faster alternatives like this Chrome extension: [Auto Click/Auto Fill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-click-auto-fill/iapifmceeokikomajpccajhjpacjmibe).

A search for `autoclickers` can help you figure out the best alternatives for your use case and there are plenty of approaches in many different languages.